# Can multiple modules share a frontName in routes.xml?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, routing

In my current project I have developed several modules to add different pieces of functionality. I'd like the admin of each module to be managed from a shared frontName, for example:

- Company_ProductModule (/admin/company/product/index...)
- Company_CategoryModule (/admin/company/category/index...)
- Company_CustomerModule (/admin/company/customer/index...)

I have another module, Company_AdminModule, which has this `adminhtml/routes.xml`:

```
<router id="admin">
    <route id="company" frontName="company">
        <module name="Company_AdminModule">
    </route>
</router>
```

The admin module has an `adminhtml/menu.xml` as follows:

```
<menu>
    <add id="Company_Admin::main" title="Company Name" module="Company_Admin" />
</menu>
```

Each module has an `adminhtml/menu.xml` as follows:

```
<menu>
    <add id="Company_Product::index" title="Product Management" module="Company_Product" parent="Company_Admin::main" action="company/product/" />
</menu>
```

This works in so far as the menu items are all added, and the URLs all look correct. However visiting each link added by a module which isn't `Company_AdminModule` just redirects to the admin homepage, I guess because it's looking for the controller in the `Company_AdminModule` module.

Is there any way to split out the controllers under this frontName, so each can sit within the correct module's `Controller/Adminhtml/` directory?

Ultimately this is desirable because each additional module should be able to add to the admin menu (which it can) but also add to the URL structure in a 'neat' way.

Comment: What does the `router.xml` file look like for your other extensions?

Comment: I don't have one at the moment - with what I want, it didn't make sense to add one with the same `id` and `frontName`, is this assumption flawed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've honestly never tried, but best I can make out looking at examples from core, you should just need to add:

```
<router id="admin">
    <route id="company">
        <module name="Company_OtherModule">
    </route>
</router>
```

To each of your other extensions in order to register the modules controllers for that route.

Comment: So simple, and works perfectly, thanks Peter!

Comment: it works ! , didn't know we can do this . Thanks